# Can I conditionally compile "Select Case"?

Tags: vb.net

The MSDN article on `#If Then #Else` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx) gives me the basics on conditionally compiling conditional statements.

I happen to have longer lists of declarations that must be initialized differently, based upon multiple platforms. Am I required to use `#ElseIf` at compile time, or is there a `#Select Case` option too?

Comment: According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx), no there isn't, but select case is just a different way of writing elseif (albeit with potential fall throughs :))

Comment: Using some sort of configuration file could be simpler and more flexible than those conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no `#Select Case` directives in VB .Net ([as pointed out by Icepickle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx))

According to [Conditional Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x435tkbk.aspx), you can define compilation constants `#Const` and test them to include or exclude blocks of code.

If you have a lot of different architectures/platforms, maybe it is better to write a different file for each platform, and protect the file with the constant check

First you declare an interface so the rest of your code will always be able to find what it needs :

```
Public Interface IPlatformDependant
    Property Test1 As Integer
    'Define here all the parameters used by your application
End Interface
```

File platform1.vb :

```
#If Platform = 1
    'The code for the first platform
    Public Class PlatformDependant
        Implements IPlatformDependant

        Public Property Test1 As Integer Implements IPlatformDependant.Test1

    End Class
#End If
```

File platform2.vb :

```
#If Platform = 2
    'The code for the second platform
    Public Class PlatformDependant
        Implements IPlatformDependant

        Public Property Test1 As Integer Implements IPlatformDependant.Test1

    End Class
#End If
```

In your project designer, you define `platform` to which you want, and only one class `PlatformDependant` will be used at a time. The classname can even stay the same...

The Interface here is optional, but it makes you sure that all your classes implements the required method.